# What is this strip hanging down inside my dryer? Anyone know?

Tags: dryer

[image]

What is this hanging in my dryer???
Is this the rear drum felt?

Comment: Looks like drum felt I'm assuming its not made of rubber?

Answer (score 4):

Based on your description and the photo it appears to be the drum felt. The felt is the seal between the rotating drum and the stationary rear part of the dryer. Replacement will require removing the drum. Consider replacing the belt and the drum rollers while everything is apart.